# Java const size array allocation

Tags: java

Where are the following const size arrays allocated in Java (heap/stack)?

```
float[] arr = new float[3];
float[] arr = {0,0,0};
```

Note, that the new keyword is not used on the second line.

Comment: @chrylis: I disagree about this being a duplicate question. The usage of the initializer list is not discussed in the linked Question.

Comment: Because it doesn't make any difference to where the object is stored. The fact that it _is_ an object means it will be stored on the heap.

Comment: The array goes on the heap, the pointer to the array is stored in the stack frame. This is true in both cases.